# Sliding window approach for DNN

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, window, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to implement the sliding windows approach and use DNN for the forecasting part. The window length = 24

What I did:
I have `x` (input) and `y` (output) in the data set. I kept the `"y"` value as it is (single array). And on the x-value:

```
def generate_input(data, sequence_length=1):
    x_data = []
    for i in range(len(data)-sequence_length+1):
        a = data[i:(i+sequence_length)]
        x_data.append(a)
    return np.array (x_data)

sequence_length = 24
x_train = generate_input(train, sequence_length)

#Shape of X train: (201389, 24)
#Shape of y train: (201412,)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(30,input_shape= (x_train.shape[1],)))
model.add(Dense(20))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer='rmsprop')
model.summary()
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, 
validation_split=0.1)
```

The error message I'm receiving:

```
Error when checking target: expected dropout_5 to have shape (20,) but got 
array with shape (1,)
```

One more question, how can I use the same approach for multivariate time series? I want to use sequences as input to predict `y`.

I changed the slicing part to:

```
x_data.append(data[i:i+sequence_length])
```

But I received an error:

> cannot copy sequence with size 24 to array axis with dimension 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`model.summary()` should show you that the output layer in your model is the Dropout layer with a shape of (None, 20). That is probably not what you want. It seems that you are trying to predict a single value. Thus you need to add a `Dense(1)` layer after. It is also highly unusual to have dropout as an output layer.

Also, x_train and y_train should have the same shape[0].

Comment: As for your second question, if you want a multivariate time series, the natural way to model it would be as a shape of (batch_size, sequence_length, n_features). Thus the network should have an input_shape of (24, 4) in that case. And you may want to use one or more convolutions at the top of your model.